# wp_query with page_author OR meta value

Tags: wordpress

I'm having some issues with getting the args to work in a wp_query. I'm sure I'm missing something small, but I just can't figure out what it is. Help appreciated!

This is where I am - after hours of work - and it's still not working. I've tried every combination I can think of and it's still not there.

To be clear, I'm looking for posts which are authored by **$user_id** ***OR*** those with a meta-key value of **$user_id**.

With this code I'm picking up all 'dm' posts including those where neither the author NOR the meta-key value is $user_id.

```
$args = array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'dm',
        array(
            'relation'      => 'OR',
            array(
                'author'    => $user_id,
            ),
            array( 
                'meta_query'    => array(
                    'key'       => 'dm_to',
                    'value'     => $user_id,
                    'compare'   => '=',
                )
            )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no great path for nested relation clauses directly with the arguments passed to `WP_Query`. Verbose relations are only available with sub query types like Meta or Taxonomy queries.

Adding an `OR` relation with an author to a meta query may be accomplished with some creative filtering.

```php
// Assign the closure to a variable to allow easy removal of the filter.
$add_author_to_where = function( $where ) use ( &$add_author_to_where ) {                                                                                                                       
    global $wpdb;                                                                                                                                                                               
    $user_id = (int) get_current_user_id();  
    $known = "meta_value = '{$user_id}' )";  
    // Replace a known portion of the meta query with the additional `OR` clause.                                                                                                                                                 
        $where['where'] = \str_replace( [                                                  
        "( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'dm_to'",         
        $known,                                                                        
    ], [                                                                               
        "( ( {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'dm_to'",       
        "{$known} OR {$wpdb->posts}.post_author = {$user_id} )", $where['where'],      
    ], $where['where'] );                                                                                                             
    // Remove the filter to prevent affecting other queries.                                                                                                                                    
    remove_filter( 'get_meta_sql', $add_author_to_where );                                                                                                                                      
    return $where;                                                                                                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                                                                              
add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', $add_author_to_where );
```

Answer (score -1):

What value does $user_id return - is it correct?
How are you declaring $user_id?

Example:

```
$user = get_user_by( 'email', 'user@example.com' );
echo 'User is ' . $user->first_name . ' ' . $user->last_name;
```

[See link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_by/)

meta_query:
Change 'compare'   => '=', to 'compare' => 'IN'